How can I associate custom regression metrics with a model that I register in the model registry in Sagemaker?
I am creating a sagemaker pipeline. As part of this pipeline, I have a model evaluation step. This model evaluation step needs to output various custom regression metrics. These custom regression metrics are outside the ones listed here. It is not clear to me from that documentation whether that list represents an exhaustive list of what metrics are allowed.
However through some simple testing, it does seem that metrics outside that list are not allowed.
Executing the evaluation step that simply returns the following results:
"regression_metrics" : {
    "r2" : {
      "value" : -1.3766111872212665,
      "standard_deviation" : 0.022653980022771227
    },
    "custom_metric_one" : {
      "value" : 1.3766111872212665,
      "standard_deviation" : 0.22653980022771227
    },
  }

and is ingested by the model registration step via s3:
model_metrics = ModelMetrics(
    model_statistics=MetricsSource(
        s3_uri=eval_report_s3_uri,
        content_type="application/json",
    )
)
...
...
model_package = model_builder.build().register(
    model_package_group_name=model_package_group_name,
    approval_status=model_approval_status,
    model_metrics=model_metrics,
)

does not work.
This seems to be a similar question where the responder suggested a "BYOC approach". However, I am not really able to follow what this means. Sounds like it means "Build Your Own Container". Seems excessive to have to build a container just to get some custom metrics.
In any case, could someone shed some more light on how to integrate custom metrics into the model registry?

Did you find out how it works? I am as clueless as you...
